# binding objects with a string and getting the column names with the name of the object in R

Tags: r, anova

I have multiple objects with a common string

```
resultsPetal.Length
resultsPetal.Width
resultsSetal.Length
resultsSetal.Width
```

and when I use cbind on them, I get this list

```
          resultSepal.Length                                        
statistic 138.9083                                                  
parameter Numeric,2                                                 
p.value   1.505059e-28                                              
method    "One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)"
data.name "dat[, i] and dat$Species"                                
          resultSepal.Width                                         
statistic 45.01204                                                  
parameter Numeric,2                                                 
p.value   1.432735e-14                                              
method    "One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)"
data.name "dat[, i] and dat$Species"
```

However, I have multiple objects and would like to join them without having to write a line for each, so I used

```
test=do.call(cbind, lapply(ls(pattern ="result"), get))
```

which gets me

```
          [,1]                                                      
statistic 1828.092                                                  
parameter Numeric,2                                                 
p.value   2.693327e-66                                              
method    "One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)"
data.name "dat[, i] and dat$Species"                                
          [,2]                                                      
statistic 1276.885                                                  
parameter Numeric,2                                                 
p.value   4.138739e-64                                              
method    "One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)"
data.name "dat[, i] and dat$Species"                                
          [,3]                                                      
statistic 138.9083                                                  
parameter Numeric,2                                                 
p.value   1.505059e-28                                              
method    "One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)"
data.name "dat[, i] and dat$Species"                                
          [,4]                                                      
statistic 45.01204                                                  
parameter Numeric,2                                                 
p.value   1.432735e-14                                              
method    "One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)"
data.name "dat[, i] and dat$Species"
```

As you can see, I have lost the object name and I have absolutely no clue how to work around this. What can I do?

Here is the full code for reproducibility

```
dat <- iris# remove one level to have only two groups
#dat <- subset(dat, Species != "setosa")
dat$Species <- factor(dat$Species)# boxplots and t-tests for the 4 variables at once
for (i in 1:4) { # variables to compare are variables 1 to 4
  boxplot(dat[, i] ~ dat$Species, # draw boxplots by group
          ylab = names(dat[i]), # rename y-axis with variable's name
          xlab = "Species"
  )
  print(oneway.test(dat[, i] ~ dat$Species)) # print results of t-test
  assign(paste0("result", names(dat[i])), (oneway.test(dat[, i] ~ dat$Species)))
}


test=cbind(resultSepal.Length, resultSepal.Width)
test=do.call(cbind, lapply(ls(pattern ="result"), get))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few approaches you could use:

Use `mget`:

```
do.call(cbind, mget(ls(pattern = 'result')))
```

Use `sapply`:

```
sapply(ls(pattern ="result"), get)
```

Give names to the list:

```
l <- ls(pattern ="result")
do.call(cbind, lapply(setNames(l,l), get))
```

Comment: thank you very much! it worked perfectly

Comment: @dm_00 please consider accepting the answer